# How to convert Turf.js polygon to WKT

Tags: geo, turfjs, wkt

I'm using Turf.js to generate [circle](https://turfjs.org/docs/#circle) geometry from point and radius, using the circle functions. Example:

`c = turf.circle([0.0, 0.0], 100, {steps:1000, units:'kilometers'})`

The returned result is [`Feature`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.2) object, and the only way I managed to represent the geometry is by applying `c.geometry.coordinates` which returns an array.

However, my goal is to generate a WKT or at least a GeoJSON, but I haven't found a way to do so.
Does anyone know how to do it with turf.js or alternatively know of a way to get a WKT representation of a circle with center and radius as inputs?

Answer (score -2):

To get `GeoJSON` text of the feature, you can do this

```
var gjs = JSON.stringify(polygon_object);
```

(Inverse check) To parse the string `gjs` and convert it back to object (GeoJSON) again

```
var ojn = JSON.parse(gjs);
```

Live code:-

```js
const pgon = turf.polygon(
    [
      [
        [50.848677, 4.338074],
        [50.833264, 4.344961],
        [50.840809, 4.366227],
        [50.852455, 4.367945],
        [50.858306, 4.346693],
        [50.848677, 4.338074]
      ]
    ],
    { name: "pgon1" }
  );
  
  const coords0 = pgon.geometry.coordinates[0];
  
  // Create WKT of the polygon
  var phead = `POLYGON((`;
  var ptail =  `))`;
  var pbody = "";
  var cur_xy = "";
  coords0.forEach( function(item, index){
   //console.log(item, index);
   //lonlat.push([...item]); //OK
   cur_xy = item[0].toFixed(4) +" "+ item[1].toFixed(4);
   pbody += cur_xy + ","; 
  }, pbody);
  
  console.log("*WKT*", phead+pbody+cur_xy+ptail);
  
  // Create geojson of the polygon
  console.log("*GeoJSON*" + JSON.stringify(pgon));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.min.js"></script>
<p>TurfJS uses GeoJSON to represent geometric features. Here a polygon feature is created and its geometry / properties are manipulated.<br/><br/>The result is printed on the console.</p>
```